# How to get last generic child node with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have about 4000 websites, all have slightly different navigation html, but the end child node is always a text based node and there is no real uniformity to how the html is laid out.

how would i get the last child node for each of the li's or a's or div's in a generic mannor based on the following html examples

```
<!-- want to be able to get each span and its text -->
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#"><span>Menu Item</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Menu Item</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Menu Item</span></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- want to be able to get each a and its text -->
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- want to be able to get each a and its text -->
<div id="nav">
  <div><a href="#">Menu Item</a></div> 
  <div><a href="#">Menu Item</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Menu Item</a></div>
</div>

<!-- want to be able to get each a and its text -->
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</div>
```

these are just some of the ways that nav's have been implemented in some of the sites, all usually have a root element with the id of nav, followed by a set of children, which can have grandchildren and further.

i do not want to have to write a separate selector for each one, so i was trying to find a generic way to do each on the first child within #nav, which would then find the last child of that particular element that contained some text.

so far i have only managed to write anything that requires a custom selector for each type of nav, so im afraid i dont have any code to start with to post.

does anyone have any idea how they would find these final children with jquery?

Comment: You do not have several root elements with `id="nav"` in the same document, right?

Comment: no, there is only ever one id="nav" as id's are supposed to be unique

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, it may be enough to just select each `<a>` within `#nav` e.g. `#nav a { /*css*/ }` -- that would work for most styling, but probably not for repositioning.

Comment: @StephenP, cloning, styling, repositioning, event hooking... everything :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way with single statement/selector:

```
$("#nav").children().each(function(i, item) {
    alert($(item).find(':not(:has(*))').text());
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qUx4A/

A little explanation:

1. $("#nav").children().each()   - do the body for each element in the #nav element (for each li, a, div....
2. :has(*)   - select element, that has any child element
3. :not(:has(*))   - negative of 2. (select element that has NOT any child element) - most inner
4. .text()   - text content of such most inner element

Hope, that's enought, I'm not sure I can explain it more precise. :)

Comment: +1 Very nice. Could you please also explain it? I am confused.

Comment: +1, I was about to post something similar. @Starx, `:not(:has(*))` matches *leaf* elements: elements that do not (`:not()`) have (`:has()`) any element descendant (`*`).

Comment: works on everything except the list of a's within a div, but, i can throw in an if hasChildren find else text() in that loop and that will be able to match pretty much everything. `$("#nav").children().each(function(i, item) {
    if($(item).children().length > 0) {
        alert($(item).find('*:not(:has(*))').text());
    } else {
        alert($(item).text());
    }
});`

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, missed the last example. Your condition should handle it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var container = $('#nav');
var children = container.children();
var element = children.eq(0);
while(children.length) {
    children = children.children();
    if (children.length)
        element = children.eq(0);
}
var elements = container.find(element.get(0).tagName);
```

It stores the deepest child in `element` and afterwards it selects all of those children accordingly to the found `tagName`. It works in all your examples. It fails if you have a nested element of the same type.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/T2gYR/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what i came up with:

```
$('.nav').each(function(){
    console.log('Nav '+$(this).index());
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        var $d = $(this);
        while($d.children().length==1){
            $d = $($d.children()[0]);
        }
        console.log($d.text());
        console.log($d);
        console.log('');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymjaG/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
$("#nav").children(":last-child").text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/uhN94/

Comment: this only appears to bring back the text "Item 3" and not "Item 1" "Item 2" and "Item 3"

Comment: do you want all the text? or just the last child of each #nav element?

Comment: each last child of #nav (ie. the 3 li's, div's or a's are all siblings, so i would like the last child of each of those)

Comment: `:last-child` does not get the last descendent of a node, it get the last one of the immediate children of the node. In all cases from the OP examples in the question this will get the third of the three children. OP wants the deepest descendent within each of the `id="nav"` node's children.

Answer (score 0):

IDs ***must*** be unique.  Change it to a class and do the following:

```
$('.nav').children(':last-child').text()
```

Comment: He's talking about the same navigation for different websites. That id is unique.